# data While Cakephp

Tags: while-loop, cakephp-2.3

I'm developing an application with cakephp.
I need to separate the results find('all') for group.
for example my table has the fields: Name; Group.
I want to make a select group by using criteria.
My Controller:

```
public function print(){
    $this->loadModel('Nomevento');
    $total = $this->Nomevento->find('count');
    $i=1;
    while($i<=$total) {
        $this->set('grupo', $this->Lista->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Lista.nomevento_id' => $i))));
        $i++;
    }

}
```

How do I collect these data in view?

My view:

```
<?php foreach ($grupo as $grupos): ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="tablelinha"><?php echo $grupos['Nomevento']['nome']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tablelinha"><?php echo $grupos['Lista']['data']; ?></td>
        <td class="tablelinha"><?php echo $grupos['Lista']['dia']; ?></td>
        <td class="tablelinha"><?php echo $grupos['Lista']['hora']; ?></td>
        <td class="tablelinha"><?php echo $grupos['Igreja']['nome']; ?></td>
        <td class="tablelinha"><?php echo $grupos['Responsavel']['responsavel']; ?></td>
        <tr><td colspan="5" class="tablelinha"><?php echo $grupos['Lista']['obs']; ?></td></tr>
    </tr>
</table><p></p>
```

The while is working but is displaying only the last result.
My Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `lista_batismo`.`nomeventos` AS `Nomevento` WHERE 1 = 1 SELECT `Lista`.`id`, `Lista`.`data`, `Lista`.`dia`, `Lista`.`hora`, `Lista`.`obs`, `Lista`.`igreja_id`, `Lista`.`responsavel_id`, `Lista`.`nomevento_id`, `Igreja`.`id`, `Igreja`.`codigo_ccb`, `Igreja`.`nome`, `Responsavel`.`id`, `Responsavel`.`responsavel`, `Responsavel`.`comum`, `Nomevento`.`id`, `Nomevento`.`nome`, `Nomevento`.`prioridade` FROM `lista_batismo`.`listas` AS `Lista` LEFT JOIN `lista_batismo`.`igrejas` AS `Igreja` ON (`Lista`.`igreja_id` = `Igreja`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lista_batismo`.`responsavels` AS `Responsavel` ON (`Lista`.`responsavel_id` = `Responsavel`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lista_batismo`.`nomeventos` AS `Nomevento` ON (`Lista`.`nomevento_id` = `Nomevento`.`id`) WHERE `Lista`.`nomevento_id` = 1 SELECT `Lista`.`id`, `Lista`.`data`, `Lista`.`dia`, `Lista`.`hora`, `Lista`.`obs`, `Lista`.`igreja_id`, `Lista`.`responsavel_id`, `Lista`.`nomevento_id`, `Igreja`.`id`, `Igreja`.`codigo_ccb`, `Igreja`.`nome`, `Responsavel`.`id`, `Responsavel`.`responsavel`, `Responsavel`.`comum`, `Nomevento`.`id`, `Nomevento`.`nome`, `Nomevento`.`prioridade` FROM `lista_batismo`.`listas` AS `Lista` LEFT JOIN `lista_batismo`.`igrejas` AS `Igreja` ON (`Lista`.`igreja_id` = `Igreja`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lista_batismo`.`responsavels` AS `Responsavel` ON (`Lista`.`responsavel_id` = `Responsavel`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lista_batismo`.`nomeventos` AS `Nomevento` ON (`Lista`.`nomevento_id` = `Nomevento`.`id`) WHERE `Lista`.`nomevento_id` = 2 SELECT `Lista`.`id`, `Lista`.`data`, `Lista`.`dia`, `Lista`.`hora`, `Lista`.`obs`, `Lista`.`igreja_id`, `Lista`.`responsavel_id`, `Lista`.`nomevento_id`, `Igreja`.`id`, `Igreja`.`codigo_ccb`, `Igreja`.`nome`, `Responsavel`.`id`, `Responsavel`.`responsavel`, `Responsavel`.`comum`, `Nomevento`.`id`, `Nomevento`.`nome`, `Nomevento`.`prioridade` FROM `lista_batismo`.`listas` AS `Lista` LEFT JOIN `lista_batismo`.`igrejas` AS `Igreja` ON (`Lista`.`igreja_id` = `Igreja`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lista_batismo`.`responsavels` AS `Responsavel` ON (`Lista`.`responsavel_id` = `Responsavel`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lista_batismo`.`nomeventos` AS `Nomevento` ON (`Lista`.`nomevento_id` = `Nomevento`.`id`) WHERE `Lista`.`nomevento_id` = 3 SELECT `Lista`.`id`, `Lista`.`data`, `Lista`.`dia`, `Lista`.`hora`, `Lista`.`obs`, `Lista`.`igreja_id`, `Lista`.`responsavel_id`, `Lista`.`nomevento_id`, `Igreja`.`id`, `Igreja`.`codigo_ccb`, `Igreja`.`nome`, `Responsavel`.`id`, `Responsavel`.`responsavel`, `Responsavel`.`comum`, `Nomevento`.`id`, `Nomevento`.`nome`, `Nomevento`.`prioridade` FROM `lista_batismo`.`listas` AS `Lista` LEFT JOIN `lista_batismo`.`igrejas` AS `Igreja` ON (`Lista`.`igreja_id` = `Igreja`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lista_batismo`.`responsavels` AS `Responsavel` ON (`Lista`.`responsavel_id` = `Responsavel`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lista_batismo`.`nomeventos` AS `Nomevento` ON (`Lista`.`nomevento_id` = `Nomevento`.`id`) WHERE `Lista`.`nomevento_id` = 4
```

Thanks for your attention;

Comment: You are overwriting `grupo` by doing `$this->set('grupo')` inside the `while` loop which is why you only see the last result. Perhaps you should do your `while` loop and add to an array, ie `$data[] = ` and when you are done, outside of the loop, you set it `$this->set('grupo', $data)`;

Answer (score 0):

It looks your are counting records so it would return only INT. 
I wouldn't use **$this->loadModel('Nomevento');** You should define properly relations between your models (Nomevento and Lista).

Comment: Hello
I do not know if I was clear in my post.
I was doing well:

My controller: